# can the wacom tablets be used to write chinese character

Tags: tablet, wacom, chinese

well i am rather new to linux and my family would like to use it as well but they would want to use a wacom tablet to write instead. With my past experience with linux many basic programs that would work with windows didnt really work on linux. In order to write in chinese with the wacom tablet i must install a chinese package from wacom but i do not know if it will work. Will the package in fact work with linux?

Comment: If the package is what I think (a kind-of input driver for Windows and Mac) no, it won't work in Linux. You should ask Wacom for Linux support...